# Jquery Datatable -Is it possible to bind href property of link with razor syntax dynamically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am using [Jquery Datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin. I am showing list of employee details with an provision to edit using the above plugin. My questioon is

Is it possible to set href property of the edit link dynamically along with razor syntax of MVC ?

If not what is the alternate solution to navigate to edit page ?

**HTML markup is**

```
        table = $("#dataTableMenuRole").dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("LoadGridView", "MenuSettings")",                
            "method": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.roleId = $("#ddlRoles").val()
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "MenuName" },
            { "data": "CanAdd" },
            { "data": "CanEdit" },
            { "data": "CanDelete" },
            { "data": "CanView" },
            { "data": "MenuRoleId" }

        ],            
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "targets": 5,
            "bSortable": false,
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-info" 
                href="@Url.Action("Edit", new {id= data })"' >'+
               //Here data cannot be assigned as shown
                        '<i class="fa fa-edit"></i>'+
                    '</a>'
            }

        }]

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to render an HTML link like this (apologies for any quote errors!):

```
return '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/Edit/' + full[5] + '"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
```

The `full` parameter is the full datasource for the current row, so assuming `MenuRoleId` is the Id you want to use, you access it using `full[5]`

You could use Razor syntax to create the url, but it means that the datatables javascript code would need to be in View, which is not ideal.