# How to bind checkbox value dynamically from database using jQuery Datatables plugin

Tags: checkbox, binding, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://www.datatables.net) plugin for displaying data. Here I have a column with checkbox which should be checked or unchecked according to the values from the database, i.e. if the value from the db is `true` checkbox should be checked and if value from db is `false` checkbox should be unchecked.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
table = $("#dataTableMenuRole").dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Url.Action("LoadGridView", "MenuSettings")",                
            "method": "POST",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": function (d) {
                d.roleId = $("#ddlRoles").val()
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { "data": "MenuName" },
            { "data": "CanAdd" }               

        ],            
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            "targets": 1,
            "bSortable": false,
            "mRender": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<input type="checkbox" class="minimal" checked="'+data+'"/>'
            }
        }]
    });
```

**The JSON returned from the db is**

```
{"data":[{"MenuName":"Roles","CanAdd":true},{"MenuName":"Menu","CanAdd":true},{"MenuName":"ServiceTax","CanAdd":false}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You define `checked` attribute despite the value in `data` and checkboxes will be always checked.

> **SOLUTION**

Use the following code instead:

```
"mRender": function (data, type, full, meta) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" class="minimal"' + (data ? ' checked' : '') + '/>';
}
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfm092ks/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I think it should work and will vote after implementing it.Meanwhile if possible please clarify my another concern which is raised in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760613/jquery-datatable-is-it-possible-to-bind-href-property-of-link-with-razor-syntax) regarding using `href` attribute dynamically using JqueryDatatables

Comment: @ksg, your another question already has a correct answer so I just voted it up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer mate.I am curious to know what is the importants of brackets`()` here .`(data ? ' checked' : '') `

Comment: @ksg, brackets allow clause surrounded to be executed first, see [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com does this two way binding? so if i submit my form i could get the value of binded checkbox ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841640/jquery-datatable-alway-showing-the-initially-checked-or-uncheck-values-only